# Map with two promises returns two arrays but only want one

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I'm trying to speed something up and make it so that food and drink can be added to an order at the same time.  So I create a promise that will resolve when both are done.  Then I put both of those in another promise that will resolve when all the orders are done.

```
orders = [
  {'name': 'john'},
  {'name': 'sam'},
]

const p = orders.map((order)=>{
    return Promise.all([
        add_food(order),
        add_drink(order),
    ])
})
return Promise.all(p)

function add_food(order){
   retrun Promise.resolve(order)
}
```

What I'm getting is an array with things that are duplicated.

```
[
  [ "order_1", "order_1"],
  [ "order_2", "order_2"]
]
```

Which actually makes sense.  I'm hitting a road block though as to how to resolve this problem and restructure it to return

```
[ "order_1", "order_1"]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add a `.then(_ => order)` after the `Promise.all` to return the order when food and drink promises are resolved :

```
const p = orders.map(order => {
  return Promise.all([
    add_food(order),
    add_drink(order),
  ]).then(_ => order)
})

return Promise.all(p)
```